# Create and play audio from google translate in java

Tags: java, audio, translate

I'm trying to take what the user types and send it through google translate to get an audio file. The first part of my code works fine and I can get a working MP3/wav/etc file, but I can't find a way to get the created audio file to play in my project. I am mostly getting the following error:

```
javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input URL
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
```

Does that have to do with the way the audio file is being made? It happens when i make it create a .wav as well. Heres my code:

```
    //take what the user types and make it into a audio file
    try{
        URL url = new URL("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q="+word);
        HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.76");
        InputStream audioSrc = urlConn.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream read = new DataInputStream(audioSrc);
        OutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(new File("words.mp3"));
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = read.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outstream.write(buffer, 0, len);                    
        }
        outstream.close();              
    }catch(IOException e){
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    //attempting to play audio
    try {
            AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResource("words.mp3"));
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioInputStream);
            clip.start();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any ideas on how I can create and play a file from google translate?

clip was initialized earlier in my code - Clip clip;